# check if list of integers is ascending

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, racket, typed-racket

I am trying to write a function to check if a list of integers is strictly ascending or not. I have the following:

```
(: ascending : (Listof Integer) -> Boolean)
;; test whether a list of integers is *strictly* ascending
(define (ascending x)
  (match x
    ('() #f)
    ((cons hd tl)
     (cond
       ((< hd (second x)) #t)
       ((> hd (second x)) #f)
       (else (ascending tl))))))
```

It works for the first three checks but not the last three as given below:

```
(check-expect (ascending (list 1 2 3 4 5)) #t)
(check-expect (ascending (list 5 4 3 2 1)) #f)
(check-expect (ascending (list 5 1 2 3 4)) #f)
(check-expect (ascending (list 1 2 3 5 4)) #f)
(check-expect (ascending (list 1 3 2 4 5)) #f)
(check-expect (ascending (list 1 2 3 4 1)) #f)
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong because I have to do the following:

1. Check if the list is empty and raise an error. Done. Tick.
2. If the there are only two elements on the list, compare `hd` and `tl` and if `hd` < `tl` then `#t`, if not then `#f`. Done Tick.
3. Other do the two comparison for all entire list until you have a value `#t` or `#f`.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems.

First, you're missing a case for a list with only 1 element, which should be the base case, and return `#t`. Otherwise, you'll use `(second x)` on a list with only 1 element, which is an error.

Next, when the list has 2 or more elements, it's ascending if the first element is less than the second element *and* the tail of the list is also ascending. You're only checking the first two elements. Your `else` clause only runs when the first and second elements are equal, because the first two `cond` checks handle `<` and `>`. The recursive call isn't a separate case, it's combined with the case where the first two elements are ascending.

```
(define (ascending x)
  (match x
    ('() #f) ;; Empty list is error
    ((cons hd '()) #t) ;; 1-element is success
    ((cons hd tl)
     (if (< hd (second x))
         (ascending tl)
         #f))))
```

The `if` can also be simplified to:

```
(and (< hd (second x)) (ascending tl))
```

Comment: Thank you SO SO SO much Mr. Barmar! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function `#'<` takes any number of arguments, you can simply do:

```
(apply #'< '(1 2 3 4)) => T
```

Comment: This question is about Typed Racket, not CL, but your answer would be correct if you simply removed the `#'` and changed `T` to `#t`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to use pattern matching to solve this, you can use more sophisticated patterns to break your problem down into separate parts.

```
(: ascending? : (Listof Integer) -> Boolean :)
(define (ascending? xs)
  (match xs
    [(list)           #f] ;; empty list is not considered ascending
    [(list a)         #t] ;; single-element list is always ascending
    ;; match first two elements (a, b) and remaining elements as c
    ;; a should be less than b, and recurse
    [(list a b c ...) (and (< a b) (ascending? (cons b c)))]))
```

To me, this read a lot better than the `'()` or `(cons ...)` style matches. And because we used a more expressive pattern in the third case, it keeps the code that actually does stuff really simple.

```
(ascending? '())               ;; => #f
(ascending? '(1))              ;; => #t
(ascending? '(1 2))            ;; => #t
(ascending? '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))  ;; => #t
(ascending? '(1 2 3 1))        ;; => #f
```

I should mention, there's nothing wrong with the other style of patterns you were using. I just think its easier to read when the patterns are consistent. So instead of matching `'()` with `cons` and `list` etc, if you wanted to use the quoted-style of patterns, use them for each case so that it's easier to see which cases you're handling.

This `ascending?` procedure operates the same, just using a different style of pattern matching expressions

```
(: ascending? : (Listof Integer) -> Boolean :)
(define (ascending? xs)
  (match xs
    [`()               #f]
    [`(,a)             #t]
    [`(,a . (,b . ,c)) (and (< a b) (ascending? (cons b c)))]))
```

---

One more thing: You said ...

> Check if the list is empty and raise an error. Done. Tick.

Returning `#f` isn't raising an error. If you truly intend to raise an error if someone passes in an empty list, then you should use the `error` procedure

```
...
(match xs
  [(list) (error 'ascending? "empty list given")]
  ...
```

Comment: @benrudgers that's unrelated to this procedure. It looks like the OP wants to return `#f` for the question "is this list in ascending order?" when and empty list is used as an input. I personally think it should return `#t` because an empty list is not *not* in ascending order. The last part of my answer addresses the potential for throwing and error tho too.

Answer (score 0):

For me, sometimes it is helpful to stick with the higher level abstractions in the problem description rather than decomposing the problem to fit into a programming pattern such as pattern matching.

### Specification

For example a strictly ordered list can be said to have two *mathematical* properties:

1. The list is sorted (monotonic).
2. The list length is equal to the cardinality of the set containing all the list elements.

### Implementation

Working from that more mathematical specification:

```
 #lang typed/racket
 (: strictly-ordered-list? : (Listof Integer) -> Boolean)
 (define (strictly-ordered-list? xs) 
   (define sorted (sort xs <))
     (and (equal? xs sorted)
       (= (set-count (list->set xs))
          (length sorted))))
```

### Discussion

The implementation is written at the abstraction layer we're interested in, lists. It tests the properties of lists and doesn't get bogged down in iterating over and comparing elements. Potentially, it trades a bit of speed, but usually for interesting sized data O(n log n) versus O(n) is not likely to be the bottle  neck.

Comment: *Potentially, it trades a bit of speed, but usually for interesting sized data O(n log n) versus O(n) is not likely to be the bottleneck.* The cases where we *just* want to check if elements are sorted instead of sorting them unconditionally are exactly the ones where complexity matters. A check is generally expected to be a simpler operation and here you are breaking this expectation, so it starts with a negative score, even when taking the pragmatic view into account. What are we gaining in counterpart? the idea that expressing a high-level...

Comment: ... property is sufficient to implement it. A logical formula suited for proofs
or abstract reasoning does not automatically translate well into operational
steps. Even though you should not prematurely optimize, there is a cerain kind
of parcimony that is expected from an implementation, in particular for such
basic things. See also: http://accidentallyquadratic.tumblr.com/

Comment: @coredump I am biased in favor of profiling an actual application over armchair optimizations theories; starting with something correct and then seeing if it needs to be faster; and readable maintainable code. I often try to follow this fellow's advice: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nhFqf_46ZQ when it comes to designing programs.

Comment: (1) Since you didn't define sort, I can assume this is the Racket one, which doesn't remove identical elements: your "set" property is not going to hold; and nowhere in the documentation it is guaranteed  that `sort` returns the same list when it is already sorted. It could be a copy. Correct code shouldn't rely on an implementation detail like this (you are using `eq?`). (2) Why would fast code be necessarily hard to read? `(loop for (a b) on list while b always (< a b))` in CL is correct and fast. Profiling is great but no excuse for bad design. Lamport would not write an O(n.log n) version.

Comment: @coredump Changed `eq?` to `equal?` which is proper for pairs. Thanks for pointing out my 12am *implementation* error regarding the properties of *lists*. I don't understand your point about sets. The comparison is between the cardinality of a set and the number of elements in a list. If the values are different then the list contains duplicates. Yes `sort` is built in to #lang racket because it is better tested than anything I could roll myself. Curious how the loop would return different error messages regarding montonicity versus unique values.

Comment: I;m interested because different error messages might be useful in activities such debugging, handling diverse inputs, and observing statistical properties of the input source.

Comment: Ok, I get what you are doing with the intermediate set now and stand corrected. Thanks for the clarification. Regarding error messages, monotonicity vs. unicity... well, the predicate just need to tell us whether the list is strictly sorted or not. The rest is implementation. That you have two cases to consider is due to the way you modelled the problem. The loop checks that consecutive elements are strictly increasing, which is sufficient to check the desired property on the list by transitivity.

Comment: If you defined a sorted list as the concatenation of two sorted sublists (where end1 < start2), you would have to consider even more cases and potentially report errors in all of those situations, but that does not mean that this is a desirable approach.

Comment: @coredump Working with lists as the abstraction facilitates writing a predicate where a list is `monotonic /\ not strictly monotonic`.  Any predicate that can be determined by a DFA can be determined by a parser, the converse is not true. Being able to write this particular predicate as a loop is just a lucky accident in the business logic. It's not generalizable to lists of integers.

Comment: Replace `<` by `<=`, or generalize with a comparison function taken as an argument if you want. The comparison function is what determines whether the order is strict or not, and in turn whether the list is strictly or weakly monotonic. This is not a lucky accident, it is an inductive definition following the very definition of sorted lists. I prefer my iterative inductive processes to be written as loops, that's all. I understand the desire to express only What is computed without detailing How it is done, though. But doesn't the loop almost read like a specification?

Comment: @coredump `<=`  does not determine whether the length of the list matches the cardinality of the set of it's elements. It matches both strictly monotonic and lists which are not strictly monotonic. `<` matches lists which are strictly monotonic. A DFA cannot match lists which are `monotonic /\ ~strictly monotonic`.  A loop is an implementation and not a specification, that's exactly Lamport's point and his concern with how many programs get written.

Comment: Let's consider only two values, "a" and "b". You are saying that in order to check whether "a" < "b" given *either* "<" or "<=" (denoted R), you check whether both "a R b" and card({a, b}) = 2. I am not following the same goal. I am checking whether "a R b" and let R define whether the order is strict or not. Both `(ascending list <)` and `(ascending list <=)` serve different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

One can also use iterative for loop with set!, though this is not normally preferred:

```
(define (asc? l)
  (define res #t)
  (for ((i (sub1 (length l)))
        #:when (not(< (list-ref l i)
                      (list-ref l (add1 i)))))
    (set! res #f)
    )
  res)
```

Testing:

```
(asc? (list 1 2 3 4 5))

(asc? (list 1 2 3 4 5 4))
```

Output:

```
#t
#f
```